# Jenkinsfile with Jira plugin - How to create a ticket

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jira, devops

We're currently using the [Jira](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira/) plugin for Jenkins and I'm trying to work out how to use it to create a ticket in Jira via Jenkins pipeline.

Looking at the documentation, it makes an offhand comment on permissions needed for a service account, but doesn't explain how to do it, let alone how to do it in pipeline. The only documentation I can find for Jenkins pipeline is in [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md).

I'm trying to avoid using `curl` or `new URL(...).openConnection()`

Am I being blind \ daft?

Use case: In a certain repo, all branches need a jira ticket number otherwise it'll get rejected. So the job creates a ticket, creates a branch in Bitbucket using the ticket number and then does some changes to an XML doc etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great pipeline code example for that
And also with the configuration needed for the Jira plugin

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Creating+Jira+Issues+From+Pipelines

Let me know if you need more help with that.. Or if it solved it for you

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my question as I was aiming at Jenkins pipeline, not JFrog. They're totally different ecosystems.